# Reading multiple csv files in a folder for individual groups

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, import, data.table

I have 44496 csv files in a folder.

If I want to read all these csv files in a single folder, I can do this:

```
files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
library(data.table)
DT = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, fread)
```

Each file has name as `wrX_Y.csv`. I have 5562 values of X and 8 values of Y.
For example, I have 8 csv files for each value of X.

```
  wr1_258, wr1_260, wr1_265, wr1_280, wr1_290, wr1_300, wr1_310,wr1_320 
  wr2_258, wr2_260, wr2_265, wr2_280, wr2_290, wr2_300, wr2_310,wr2_320
  .
  .
  .
  .
  wr5562_258, wr5562_260, wr5562_265, wr5562_280, wr5562_290, wr5562_300, wr5562_310,wr5562_320
```

I want to combine all the files belonging to a given X. For example,

```
  wr1_258, wr1_260, wr1_265, wr1_280, wr1_290, wr1_300, wr1_310,wr1_320 into a single csv
  wr2_258, wr2_260, wr2_265, wr2_280, wr2_290, wr2_300, wr2_310,wr2_320 into a single csv and so on
```

Let's say `names.list` is a vector with all the values of X. How do I read all the csv belonging to a single X, merge them and write them out

```
  for(i in names.list){
   files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
   DT = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, fread) # one read those csv files which belong to i
   fwrite(DT,paste0(i,"alldata.csv"))
  }
```

Comment: have you checked `list.files(..., recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)` to check in subfolders and get the complete path? With pattern you can choose any regex to select your files.

Comment: Okay. I have modified the question now. I specified using `path`.

Comment: So by using `patter='^X1_.*\\.csv$'` you select only the files which start with `X1_`... Also I recommend using `file.path` for file paths instead of `paste0`.

Comment: @drmariod what does the recursive argument affects in this context?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry my question was not clear so your solution does not work for me. I have modified my question now.

Comment: I would make a table of tables (my notes here http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#fread ); then use string operations to create columns for X and Y; then `fileDT[, .(xtab = rbindlist(setNames(contents, Y), id = "Y")), by=X` or something. Hard to get the syntax exactly right without an example to test on. Then you can inspect the tables and write them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be more of a `regex` than `data.table` qn. Improvement on your pattern input to `list.files` function below:

```
  for(i in names.list) {
     files <- list.files(pattern=paste0("wr", i, "_(.*).csv"), full.names=TRUE)
     DT <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
     fwrite(DT, paste0(i,"alldata.csv))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
## list all files in the folder, enter the path of folder containing .csv files
list_files <- list.files(path = 'path') 

## number of iterations 
len <- 5562
ffiles <- vector('list', length = len)

## create a dictionary
## this groups the name of files based on X values (1,2...5562)
for(i in seq(list_files))
{
    file_name <- list_files[i]
    string <- unlist(strsplit(file_name, split = '_'))[1]
    string <- gsub(pattern = '[a-z]', replacement = '', x = string)
    print(string)
    if (string %in% names(ffiles))
    {
        ffiles[[string]] <- append(ffiles[[string]], file_name)
    } else {
        ffiles[[string]] <- file_name
    }

}

## this will be used in next step
full_path <- list.files(path = 'folder_path', full.names = T)

## rbind and write all files
for (i in names(ffiles))
{
    files_path <- append(files_path, sapply(ffiles[i], function(x) list.files(path = full_path, pattern = x, full.names = T)))
    assign(paste0('df',i), do.call(rbind, lapply(files_path, fread)))
    fwrite(get(paste0('df',i), .GlobalEnv), paste0('df_',i,'.csv'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rbindlist()` function to rbind a `list` of `data.tables` and the `idcol` argument to add an extra column indicating each row's file of origin:

```
library(data.table)

# Load all files into a named list of data.tables:
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
dt_list <- lapply(files, fread)
names(dt_list) <- files # for the idcol argument in rbindlist

# Concatenate all data.tables into a single data.table, with a column
# indicating each row's file of origin.
# add use.names = TRUE if you columns are not in the same order in 
# each file.
# add fill = TRUE if some columns are not present in all files
dt <- rbindlist(dt_list, idcol = "file")

# Convert file column to a column of X and Y
dt[, fileX := gsub("_.*", "", file)]
dt[, fileX := gsub("^wr", "", fileX)]
dt[, fileY := gsub(".*_", "", file)]
dt[, fileY := gsub(".csv", "", fileY)]

# For each X, output the corresponding data.table:
for (xtype in unique(dt$fileX)) {
   # subset dt and drop file identifier columns
   xdt <- dt[fileX == xtype]
   xdt[, file := NULL]
   xdt[, fileX := NULL]
   xdt[, fileY := NULL]

   # write table:
   fwrite(xdt, file=paste0("wr", xtype, ".csv"))
}
```